# Loop through different Button Text .onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to change my Button Text when clicked.

Right now i have

```
# Script Loading Button
$(document).ready ->
  $('.loop_button').click ->
    $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Uploading...');
```

So when clicked it changes to the `fa-spinner` icon and to `Uploading...` text.

How can i insert 3 or more Strings to be displayed in the button Text. Something like:

```
["Uploading...", "Still Uploading", "This file is HUGE"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have time intervals where you want this to happen, you can do this with time-outs. The `setTimeout` function will execute a callback after the specified number of milliseconds. So, for example:

```
timeouts = []
$('.loop_button').click ->
   button = $(this)
   button.html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Uploading...')

   # switch label after 10 seconds...
   timeouts.push setTimeout ( ->
      button.html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Still Uploading')
   ), 10000

   # switch label again after 30 seconds...
   timeouts.push setTimeout ( ->
      button.html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> This File is HUGE')
   ), 30000
```

And then when your upload finishes, you should stop any pending timeouts:

```
clearTimeout timeout for timeout in timeouts
$(".loop_button").html("Start")
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gwcoffey/6JRfp/1/

Comment: I'm just getting started with JS so bare with me for a bit :) I pasted the code but it isn't working.. The `only` code i have for my button is the one i posted in my Question.

Comment: Sorry, I had a bug in my code. It is fixed now and I added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate soloution...

```
    $( ".loop_button" ).click(function() {
      $.each([ "I'm afraid. I'm afraid, Dave.","Dave, my mind is going.","There is no question about it. I can feel it." ], function( index, value ) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".loop_button").html(value);
        }, index * 3000);   
    });
});
```